# Office 365: daily quarantine reports

Tags: office365, spam-prevention, quarantine

I am looking to activate a daily quarantine report for all users under Office365 but can't seem to find the option in the new layout. It is no longer available under the "classic exchange admin center" in spam-filter. Anybody knows where I can find the option under the new Microsoft 365 Defender, or somewhere else?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Quarantine policies define what users are allowed to do to quarantined messages based on why the message was quarantined (for supported features). For more information, see [Quarantine policies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/quarantine-policies?view=o365-worldwide). Quarantine polices also control whether the affected recipients (including shared mailboxes) get periodic quarantine notifications about their quarantined messages. Quarantine notifications are the replacement for end-user spam notifications for all supported protection features (not just anti-spam policy verdicts).

Quarantine notifications are not turned on in the built-in quarantine notifications named AdminOnlyAccessPolicy or DefaultFullAccessPolicy. Quarantine notifications are turned on in the built-in quarantine policy named NotificationEnabledPolicy [if your organization has it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/quarantine-policies?view=o365-worldwide#full-access-permissions-and-quarantine-notifications). Otherwise, to turn on quarantine notifications in quarantine policies, you need to  [create and configure a new quarantine policy.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/quarantine-policies?view=o365-worldwide#step-1-create-quarantine-policies-in-the-microsoft-365-defender-portal)

In addition, to allow the 'Block sender' option in quarantine notifications to work correctly, users need to be enabled for remote Powershell. For instructions, see [Enable or disable access to Exchange Online PowerShell.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/disable-access-to-exchange-online-powershell)

Full document: [Use quarantine notifications to release and report quarantined messages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/use-spam-notifications-to-release-and-report-quarantined-messages?view=o365-worldwide)